# JavaMail download attachment from mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

How can I download attachment from a mail with Content-Type: multipart/alternative;

```
Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();

int numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount();
for(int j = 0; j < numberOfParts; j++)
{
    MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(j);

    if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition()))
    {
        part.saveFile( "C:\\Users\\Demo\\Desktop\\" + part.getFileName());

    }
 }
```

Comment: Your second `if` is redundant and should be removed.  Your `part.saveFile` line will not compile because backslashes are special characters in Java string literals.

Answer (score 0):

There's a wide variety of possible MIME structures for email.  A general solution can be quite complex since it would need to take into account signed and encrypted messages, among other issues.  Different mailers will use different MIME structure, and of course some mailers will have bugs in how they use MIME.  You need to decide which cases you need to support.

In general, multipart/alternative is used to contain different versions of the main message body, and so can be skipped because it doesn't contain any attachments.  Typically, a message with attachments will have a top level multipart/mixed content with the first body part containing the main message body.  The first part may be a simple text part, a multipart/alternative with text/plain and text/html parts, or a multipart/related with a text/html part and associated images.

Attachments will usually, but not always, have a Content-Disposition of attachment.  Attachments will usually, but not always, have a file name.

So, a good approach to start with is to only consider messages with a top level multipart/mixed content and then consider the parts after the first part to be attachments whether they say so or not.  And as I said above, signed and encrypted messages will make this more complex.